# Javascript - Array keeps being interpret as String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code -

```js
var status = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];


$(function() {
  console.log(window.status);
  console.log(typeof window.status);
  var status = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
  console.log(status);
  console.log(typeof status);

});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Outside of `$(function() {});` the `var status` is declared as an array.
Yet when it comes to logging it to console, it shows up as a String.

I repeat with the same thing inside the ready function and it behaves as it should this time. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: When i run this code, it shows an array and an object. What is the problem ?

Comment: @DalvinderSingh Check the scrollbar ;)

Comment: for me it shows the log as -
A, B, C, D, E, F and the typeof is showing string. Is this browser specific?

The last two logs are showing it as an array, as they should.

Comment: I edited the OP so you don't need to scroll in the snippet ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with other name its using default by javascript

```js
var my_status = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];


$(function() {
  console.log(window.my_status);
  console.log(typeof window.my_status);
  var status = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
  console.log(status);
  console.log(typeof status);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that status was taken by JS.

Answer (score 3):

`window.status` was the property which defined the browser's status bar text (a string). Therefore your array got automatically converted to a string.

You could prevent that from happening if you move `status` into its own closure, for example by wrapping it within a `(function(){...})();` and accessing it by `status`, not `window.status`.